# PHP mail() function can't send to @gmail.com using apache postfix on ubuntu

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, smtp, postfix-mta

I want to send an email on my website via the PHP mail() function. I've setup postfix using this tutorial from [digitalocean.com](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-postfix-as-a-send-only-smtp-server-on-ubuntu-20-04), and I can now send emails with the function to every email except those ending with @gmail.com.

This is my PHP code:

```
$mailtext = '
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">

 <title>Email Verification</title>
</head>
<body style="height: 100%; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
                    
 <p>...</p>

</body>
</html>
';

$to = $user['email'];
$subject = "subject";
$header  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
$header .= "From: no-reply@example.org\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $mailtext, $header);
```

I have searched for other answers on google, but have not found a solution yet.

EDIT:
I've just checked my logs and found out that Google has seen my email as spam and therefore not allowed it to go through. How can I make google allow my mail?

Comment: Depends on _why_ google rejected the message. "has seen as spam" certainly is _not_ the specific reason google named.

Comment: Read the duplicate for lots of suggestions on making your mail more reliable